# 402.2.1260 IIS7 Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Service

Tags: web-services, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a 3rd party webservice that runs by posting a soap message directly to a dll.

It runs perfectly on my development machine, but when I try and deploy it to Windows 2008 R2  64-bit using IIS 7 it fails, indicating error  404 2 1260 in the IIS7 log.

I have done all of the normal stuff, including:

- Setting the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions,
- Adding the Handler Mappings and setting them to Execute,
- Setting Handler Mappings Feature Permissions to Execute

but none of that helps.

When I enable Failed Request Logging, the lowest-level detail that I can get is:

- Error Code 0x800704ec
- Error Code 2147943660
- Error message  IsapiModule  This program is blocked by group policy

What is going on!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DLL was a 32-bit DLL.

By default, IIS 7 running on Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit doesn't allow 32bit dlls to run.

There's a little setting in the `Application Pool Advanced Settings` called `Enable 32-Bit Applications`.  Set it to **True** in the application pool to which your web service belongs, and it should start working!